# Android studio coloring the current execution code when debugging

Tags: android, debugging, colors, android-studio

It is hard to know where the execution is currently at when debugging so I went to file -> settings -> editor -> colors and fonts -> debugger and in execution point I set my own colors but it seems to have no effect. How can I make the current execution code line much more noticeable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android studio - coloring the current execution code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590939/android-studio-coloring-the-current-execution-code)

Comment: You aren't really allowed to repost the same question multiple times to get more attention...sorry.