# Android studio - coloring the current execution code

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

When debugging, it is hard to know where the execution point is so I went to file -> settings -> editor -> colors and fonts -> debugger and in execution point I set my own colors but it seems to have no effect. How can I make the current execution code line much more noticeable?

One small question: How can I export the settings of android studio for when I will need to re-install it?

Comment: Are you using breakpoints and stepping through your code line-by-line? Otherwise the processor is going to speed through code much faster than any human could follow, regardless of the line color.

Comment: Oh, ofcourse I mean when the code stops at a break point and I'm pressing F8 and F7

Answer (score 0):

It might have been a bug by the time you posted your question, but the modification you wrote about works with Android Studio 2.2.3.

NB: As Android Studio specifies, you can't modify a predefined theme (Darcula or Default) so if you want to change a colour, you will be asked to save the modification in a custom style using the *Save As...* button.